# How to edit a background image in tkinter in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, background

I try to edit the background image of the tkinter code but i cannot even if i rename a different picture with "landscape.png" regardless of the different picture being larger or smaller. I do not know what i can do to improve this problem, Its like this code only works with one type of picture and i dont know why. I am trying to deal with this issue for 3 days now and this is my last help resort

I have tried the above

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 600

def test_function(entry):
    print("This is the entry:", entry)

# api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city name},{country code}
# a4aa5e3d83ffefaba8c00284de6ef7c3

def format_response(weather):
    try:
        name = weather['name']
        desc = weather['weather'][0]['description']
        temp = weather['main']['temp']

        final_str = 'City: %s \nConditions: %s \nTemperature (°F): %s' % (name, desc, temp)
    except:
        final_str = 'There was a problem retrieving that information'

    return final_str

def get_weather(city):
    weather_key = 'a4aa5e3d83ffefaba8c00284de6ef7c3'
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    params = {'APPID': weather_key, 'q': city, 'units': 'imperial'}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    weather = response.json()

    label['text'] = format_response(weather)



root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='landscape.png')
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=5)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=40)
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Get Weather", font=40, command=lambda: get_weather(entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(lower_frame)
label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I expected another image to show but instead i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


    File "/Users/michal/Desktop/GUI-master/WeatherApp.py", line 41, in <module>
        background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='landscape.png')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
        Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3501, in __init__
        self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
    _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "landscape.png"
    >>>
```

Comment: Python 3.7 includes tk 8.6 which should support PNG image.  Make sure the image is not corrupted. Or it may be actually in other format, like JPG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The PhotoImage class can read `GIF` and `PGM/PPM` images from files:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")

photo = PhotoImage(file="image.pgm")
```

> If you need to work with other file formats, the `Python Imaging`
>   `Library (PIL)` contains classes that lets you load images in over 30
>   formats, and convert them to Tkinter-compatible image objects:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

You can use a PhotoImage instance everywhere Tkinter accepts an image object.

An example:

```
label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack()
```

in your code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

background_image = Image.open(image_path)
background_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image)

background_label = tk.Label(root, image = background_photo)
background_label.image = background_photo
background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

> NOTE: if you doesn't have installed PIL, just install it from cmd :
>
> `pip install Pillow`

Comment: thanks a lot! You made the answer very clear and easy to understand :)